# Perl 5.14.2-7u21deb - Error with ConfigLocal.pm (Number found where operator expected)

Tags: perl, debian

i've been expiriencing a strange issue and can't figure out the cause.

I'm trying to check an ESXi Host with the Nagiosplugin check_esx3

Whenever i call the script, i get a proper return, but right before i get the Error as follows:

```
Number found where operator expected at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Encode/ConfigLocal.pm line 13, near "$_ModLines_

1"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
```

Since any other interaction with Perl runs into same scenario, it migt be something at the very basic. Unluckily im not tat familiar with Perl.

Trying to call "enc2xs -C" i get :

```
Number found where operator expected at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Encode/ConfigLocal.pm line     13, near "$_ModLines_

1"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
 require Encode;
 require Encode;
 require Encode::Symbol;
 require Encode::Byte;
 require Encode::Config;
 require Encode::Encoder;
 require Encode::EBCDIC;
 require Encode::Alias;
 require Encode::ConfigLocal;
Can't require Encode::ConfigLocal: Attempt to reload Encode/ConfigLocal.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 16) line 1.
```

Content of /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Encode/ConfigLocal.pm :

```
 #
 # Local demand-load module list
 #
 # You should not edit this file by hand!  use "enc2xs -C"
 #
 package Encode::ConfigLocal;
 our $VERSION = $_LocalVer_;

 use strict;

 $_ModLines_

 1;
```

Perlversion info:

```
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Sep 30 2013 03:45:34
  %ENV:
    PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME="0"
  @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.14
    /usr/share/perl/5.14
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Encode/ConfigLocal.pm`. It's optional (see the source code of `Encode.pm`, the `require Encode::ConfigLocal` is wrapped in an eval block) and not part of normal perl installations. `enc2xs -C` would create a new `Encode::ConfigLocal`, but apparently there's a bug which creates an invalid file. Anyway, unless you really think you need it, just remove it.

Comment: I am not 100% satisfied that i need to remove the link for optional additions, but since i got none : Perfect! Did work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error message, a semicolon is missing on previous line:

```
package Encode::ConfigLocal;
our $VERSION = $_LocalVer_;

use strict;

$_ModLines_;
# here   __^

1;
```

Comment: @ M42: might give me a hint how to edit a readonly file, that says strictly 'use "enc2xs -C"'. If i try to edit it with an editor, it opens in readonly.

@Slaven Rezic so this doesn't work either? (cause i can't imagine that this really would fix it)